# gather large sub Matrices in MPI in c

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

i wanna make a program that calculate matrix multiplication "large matrices 1000*1000 for example"
in master-worker paradigm and select to each worker number of rows it will work on 
for example if i have  1000*1000 matrix and i got 4 processes
process 0 is master wont work on it
process 1 will get from 0 to 333
process 2 will get from 333 to 666
process 3 will get from 666 to 1000
simply here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int **alloc(int rows, int cols)
{
    int *data = (int *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    int **array= (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}
void free2D(int **mat)
{
    free(mat[0]);
    free(mat);

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int my_rank;        /* rank of process  */
    int p;          /* number of process    */
    int source;     /* rank of sender   */
    int dest;       /* rank of reciever */
    int tag = 0;        /* tag for messages */
    MPI_Status status;  /* return status for    */
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    int **mat1;
    int **mat2;
    int **mat3;
    int n,r,m;
    int i,j,k,sum;
 int start[100];
    int end[100];
    int istart,iend;
    int avg,extra,taken,temp;



    if (my_rank==0)
    {
        n=1000;
        r=1000;
        m=1000;

        mat1=alloc(n,r);
        mat2=alloc(r,m);
        mat3=alloc(n,m);

        //found = (int *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));


        MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&r, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        avg=n/(p-1);
        extra=n%(p-1);
        temp=0;

        for(i=0; i<(p-1); i++)
        {
            taken=(extra--<=0)? avg: avg+1;
            start[i]=temp;
            temp+=taken;
            end[i]=temp;
        }

         for (source=1; source<p; source++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&start[source-1],1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&end[source-1],1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }


        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<r; j++)
            {
                mat1[i][j]=1;
                MPI_Bcast(&(mat1[i][j]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                mat2[i][j]=5;
                MPI_Bcast(&(mat2[i][j]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            }
        }
    ///here i supposed to receive my sub matrices from worker


        free2D(mat1);
        free2D(mat2);
        free2D(mat3);



    }


    else{
        MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&r, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&istart,1,MPI_INT,0,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&iend,1,MPI_INT,0,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        mat1=alloc(n,r);
        mat2=alloc(r,m);
        mat3=alloc(iend-istart,m);
         for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<r; j++)
            {
                MPI_Bcast(&(mat1[i][j]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                MPI_Bcast(&(mat2[i][j]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            }
        }
        sum=0;

        for (i=istart; i<iend; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<r; k++)
                {
                    sum += mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
                }
               // printf("%d  %d\n",i,j);
               mat3[i-istart][j]=sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
/// here i supposed to send sub matrices 
 //printMat(mat3,iend-istart,m);
        free2D(mat1);
        free2D(mat2);
        free2D(mat3);

    }

    /* shutdown MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

it works fine every worker calculate its sub matrix correctly but i don't know how to send them back to master and it takes alot of time if i used MPI_Send and MPI_Recv "as its point to point messaging"
Any idea how to gather them ? i'm new to MPI btw.

Comment: `MPI_Gather()` (or `MPI_Gatherv()`) to gather, and `MPI_Scatter()`/`MPI_Scatterv))` to scatter.

Comment: can u give me example of MPI_Gatherv() in this case ? plz

Comment: Have you tried looking up the documentation for `MPI_Gather` / `MPI_Scatter` or a tutorial online? The first link that pops up in my search is [this tutorial](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/).